# Four color theorem and five color theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

> Every graph whose chromatic number is more than ____ is not planner.

---

My attempt:

The answer should be $4$ by four color theorem.

Somewhere, I read "Five color theorem"([See Theorem 6.3.8 at page no.-74](http://www.trentu.ca/academic/math/bz/gcolor.pdf)). Somewhere, there is given "Six color theorem".

> Can you give a planar graph such that chromatic number of that graph will $5$?

However, given question "Every graph whose chromatic number is more than ____ is not planner." does not seem correct. Since bipartite graph $K_{3, 3}$ has chromatic number is $2$, but it's not planar graph.

> Can you explain in formal way, please?

Comment: Not sure what the question is.  Your last point seems logically flawed:  If my claim is that no yellow bird can be a vulture you can't disprove it by showing me a red bird which is not a vulture.

Comment: @lulu, my question is : Every graph whose chromatic number is more than ____ is not planner. (what should be answer).

Comment: $K_{3,3}$ is not the only graph of chromatic number $2$. Remember that $(A \implies B) \iff (\neg B \implies \neg A)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to find for which $n$, the sentence "Every graph whose chromatic number is bigger than $n$ is not planar". This sentence is of the type $A\implies B$ where $A$ is "The chromatic number of $G$ is bigger than $n$" and $B$ is "$G$ is not planar" and your task is to find $n$ such that $A\implies B$ is true.

Of course, it won't tell you anything about graphs whose chromatic number is less or equal to $n$ but you don't really care about that.

Concerning the problem itself, $4$ is a right answer because of the four color theorem (every planar graph has chromatic number at most $4$). Since the four color theorem has been proved by a computer (they reduced all the planar graphs to just a bunch of different cases, about a million I think), most of the books show the proof of the five color theorem (which has a non-computer proof).

Note that $10^{42}$ is a right answer too, because they are not asking the smallest $n$ for which it is true. However, the expected answer is probably $4$, or at most $5$.

Comment: The proof for the five colour theorem is actually not very difficult. And it can be adapted to a "proof" for the four colour theorem that was believed to be correct for ten years (and then it was shown to be faulty).

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.